# ElaticSearch find all duplicates after removing spaces and spacial characters

Tags: elasticsearch

We have around 100,000 documents in our elastic search cluster. I am trying to find a query so that we can find out duplicate documents based on some fields.
I am able to run this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
     "duplicateCount": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "name",
          "min_doc_count": 2
        },
        "aggs": {
          "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
         }
     }
  }
}
```

But some of our documents have similar value. For example two different documents has name: "pawan" and name: "paw-an" we would like to treat them as same document. I can't find any way to say replaceAll  and then run this query. Is there any way to do it? We are using ElasticSearch 1.5 so may be its too old for such features. Thanks.

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings":{
            "employeeinfo":{
                        "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
                        "properties":{
                                    "name":{
                                              “type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "age":{
                                                "type":"long"
                                    }
                        }
            }
 }
}
```

Regards,
Pawan.

Comment: Please post your index mapping.

Comment: Sorry don’t have my laptop right now but I have updated question with somewhat similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using a [script in your `terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) instead of a field name:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
     "duplicateCount": {
        "terms": {
          "script": "_source.name.replaceAll('-', '')",
          "min_doc_count": 2
        },
        "aggs": {
          "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: ya I tried it I get this nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; and if I use lang painless I get some weird error

Comment: Oh yes sorry in 1.5 you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting)

Comment: Sorry forgot to update. Ur answer is correct but I am using aws Elasticsearch and they don’t have any way to enable it in 1.5 :(

Comment: True, [as explained here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=856840#856840), AWS ES is pretty constrained, you should consider migrating to [ES Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud) instead, which is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this won't be possible in Elasticsearch 1.5 in a single query. One solution which I can think of is you can scroll through the docs maintaining the hash set of similar fields. Iterating through 100,000 documents should not be that memory intensive.

Then you can apply the aggregation query as following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
     "duplicateCount": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "name",
          "include": ["pawan", "paw-an"],
          "min_doc_count": 2
        },
        "aggs": {
          "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
         }
     }
  }
}
```